# Задача по линейному программированию

Tags: алгоритм

Решаю из сборника задач для себя и наткнулся на такую задачу.

**Каждый из m станков может обрабатывать n типов деталей. Известны резервы времени работы станков a[i], i=1..m, и число деталей каждого вида b[j], j=1..n. Известно время обработки каждой детали на каждом станке t[i][j], i=1..m, j=1..n.
Определить план загрузки станков, обеспечивающий минимальное суммарное время работы оборудования.**

Нашел алгоритм Джонсона. Алгоритм решает задачу правильно, но не учитывая резерв времени работы. Подскажите как решить эту задачу, используя какой то алгоритм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нет никаких этапов обработки и связей между ними, так что алгоритм Джонсона тут не нужен. Это обычная задача линейного программирования.

Если обозначить искомый план загрузки как `l`, то задача минимизировать функцию
[image: целевая функция]

при ограничениях:

[image: ограничение на резерв]

[image: полнота выполнения задач]

Используйте любой алгоритм для решения задачи линейного програмирования.